# Автоперенос при фиксированной высоте родителя

Tags: html, css

У меня есть блок с фиксированной высотой, в моём случае это UL.

Мне нужно чтобы его внутренние элементы с классом 'first-li' автоматически переносились и не выходили за рамки. Float мне не походит, т.к. нужно чтобы они были столбиком.

Вот пример:

```css
.menu {
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.first-li {
  width 25%;
}
```

```html
<ul class='menu'>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Какое есть решение ?

Вот пример желаемого результата:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Куда переносились? Приведите пример желаемого результата.

Comment: Добавил. Посмотрите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С использованием `display: flex;`

```css
.menu {
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.first-li {
  width 25%;
}
```

```html
<ul class='menu'>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: эх, придется свой ответ удалить :-)

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, на минуту обогнал :С

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это решение вам поможет

```css
.menu {
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.first-li {
  width 25%;
}

.menu{
 -moz-column-count: 3; /* Для Firefox */
-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Для Safari и Chrome */
column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul class='menu'>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li class='first-li'>Список
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```